Why does the stable distribution become Gaussian at $\alpha=2$?
I'm having trouble understanding why the stable distribution turns into a Gaussian at $\alpha=2$. In my course it seems like the idea is to see this from the tail behaviour of the distribution. From Wikipedia, the tail behaviour can be expressed (for large x) by
$$
{\displaystyle f(x)\sim {\frac {1}{|x|^{1+\alpha }}}\left(c^{\alpha }(1+\operatorname {sgn}(x)\beta )\sin \left({\frac {\pi \alpha }{2}}\right){\frac {\Gamma (\alpha +1)}{\pi }}\right)} 
$$
At $\alpha=2$ this becomes a term proportional to $\frac{1}{x^3}$, which does not seem to make sense, as for a Gaussian the expected tail behaviour would be some sort of exponential.
Am I missing something, or does the equation not hold for $\alpha=2$ - and if so what is happening?

Start with the characteristic function rather than a density function (which doesn't hold for $\alpha=2$).

Specifically, at $\alpha=2$, $\sin \pi\alpha/2=0$ so that expression is zero rather than proportional to $x^{-3}$

Use the characteristic function. From wikipedia the stable characteristic function is given by
$$  
  \exp \left( it\mu - | c t|^\alpha ~~[ 1-i\beta \operatorname{sgn}(t) \Phi ] \right)
$$
where $\Phi=\begin{cases}\tan\frac{\pi\alpha}{2}& \alpha \not= 1, \\ -\frac{2}{\pi}\log | t | & \alpha=1. \end{cases} $
Here $\mu$ is location, $c>0$ is scale, $\beta$ indicates skew and $ \alpha$ is the stability parameter.
Now take the limit when $\alpha\rightarrow 2$, the result will be
$$
\exp \left( it\mu -c^2 t^2  \right) 
$$
which is characteristic function of some normal distribution. It is interesting that the skew parameter $\beta$ disappears in the limit.

When you type \mathrm{exp} rather than just \exp, then 2\mathrm{exp} x looks like $2\mathrm{exp} x$ instead of $2\exp x,$ without the horizontal spacing. With \exp, the amount of horizontal spacing varies with the context.
